# Drawing a pie chart in gray scale using matplolib of python

Tags: python, grayscale

I try to draw a pie chart in grayscale using matplolib of python.
But what I have is grayscale data of color which are vary between 0 and 255
Using these grayscale data, can I draw gray scale pie chart?

```
data = [10,20,30]
colors = [20, 100, 150] # grayscale data
plt.pie(data, colors = colors)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass color in as str:

```
data = [10,20,30]
colors = [20, 100, 150] # grayscale data
plt.pie(data, colors = [str(x/255) for x in colors])
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. i thought it must be a simple and beautiful just like you suggest.